# Формула суммы ряда переменных

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться как написать формулу, проблема в сумме:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не только к Swift вопрос конечно относится. Пример как развернуть формулу: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используйте вложенные циклы. Для примера:

```
var sum = 0
for i in 1...3 {
    for j in 1...2 {
        sum += a[i][j]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

так как A и B не зависят от i и j  то можно просто перемножить все 4 и получить результат. A*B*m*n

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.